# Would internally linking from inside a Silo to another Silo cause any negative SEO issues?

Tags: seo, site-structure

I am of the impression that internal linking, should ideally go up and down a site's structure, with horizontal linking restricted to Parent level pages only.  Even then, these should only really link to other Parent level pages.

For the purpose of this question, let's say I have created a basic eCommerce site structure, as follows:

[image]

For the most part, I would have followed a Physical Internal linking approach, so that URLs would typically be:

```
www.example.com/product-category/product-name/
www.example.com/post-category/post-name/
```

Supported by virtual internal links, on each page.

Taking 'Blog Post A' from the above image, we can see that it is linking to 'Product C'; since the Post is about Product C.  Furthermore, we can see that Blog Post A is breaking out from its Silo (I have just realised I have not placed the Blog Categories in but let's assume they are beneath 'Blogs') and linking to a Product page, within a differing Silo.  I am of the understanding that this is generally not good practice.

As such, should I:

1. `rel=nofollow` Blog Post links to Product pages? (If doing this, maybe link to the Product Category as to send some link juice over which would filter down to the Product Page anyway; albeit diluted).
2. Restructure the site, so that each Blog Category becomes a Child Category within each Product Category (Not sure of the implications with the Taxonomy here, since Product Pages are separate Custom Post Types)?
3. Point the Blog Post to the Product Category rather than Product page?
4. Do nothing as search results would recognise that it is a Blog Post?  If not recognise a Blog Post, at least recognise the Product Page through correct Schema integration and make exceptions for certain internal links?

Comment: You are way over thinking this silo thing. It is pure SEO B.S. Just create cross links how it makes sense for your users and site and stop worrying. Life is too short for such trivialities! Cheers!!

Comment: What a waste of time... I highly recommend you ditch the current non-sense SEO guide you are reading. No-follow does not allow webmasters to manipulate the flow of juice... it hasn't for over a decade.

Comment: @closetnoc Admittedly, I am often too 'academic' at times.  Whether it affects SEO or not, I do believe that a 'Silo Approach' offers some kind of benefit.  Though, I do agree on the notion of linking where it makes sense.  :-)

Comment: @SimonHayter I am not reading any one guide in particular.  Just stuff I have been coming across; particularly contradictory information.  Such contradictions suggesting that subjectivity plays a big part in SEO, which is not surprising really, since search engine Algorithms are not placed in the public domain.

Comment: @SimonHayter *'No-follow does not allow webmasters to manipulate the flow of juice'* ... Are you referring to 'PageRank Sculpting' here?  If so, then I agree since Google publically stated that they were implementing measures to prevent the manipulation of Link Juice.  If you mean that `rel=nofollow` does not prevent Link Juice from flowing, then I would have to respectfully disagree.  Not only does Google state otherwise here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en (Admittedly, it is an old article) but my own 45 day A/B Test, suggests that the `rel=nofollow` tag is honoured.

Comment: The whole silo thing was largely debunked years ago. Also, we kinda get disturbed by those who are mislead by the SEO bull because it leads good people down the wrong path. You are learning fast. Clearly! For what it is worth, Google does tell you how it works but not where everyone else is looking. You do have to dig and know what you are looking for and looking at. Just take all the non-technical SEOs with a lot of salt. They are largely guessing. Poorly. But guessing non-the-less.

Comment: I want you to know the thing I like about you is that you are eager, read, are thinking and processing information, ask questions, etc. I want you to know that I really do appreciate it! It makes me happy. We are protective of our people and do sometimes say, Skip that part., in an effort to ultimately help shorten the journey. We do this out of webmaster brotherhood. Cheers!!

Comment: nofollow does not improve the rankings of other pages... that's my point. Google no longer uses the same distribution it once did almost 2 decades ago. Reserve noindex and nofollow for sensitive pages or pages that you do not want indexed or followed to other sensitive pages.